# testing join record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

A method for creating a user, has a consequential method for creating a join table record

```
  if @user.save
    @roleshopuser = Rolehopuser.create(user_id: @user.id, shop_id: @site.shop_id, role_id: params[:role_id])
```

However, when testing this method, teh test hits an error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant UsersController::Rolehopuser
```

The parent model defines

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roleshopusers
```

and the method works in the applications normal processing.

How can this test be written to allow the creation of a join table record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need to edit the variable `@roleshopuser` where 's' is missing.

```
@roleshopuser = Roleshopuser.create(user_id: @user.id, shop_id: @site.shop_id, role_id: params[:role_id])
```

Comment: another face-palm moment.